# extra string is automatically inserting after converting time to POSIXct in R

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

In the original data frame

[image]

I converted the last column to POSIXct using the following command:

```
ordered$Start.Time <- strptime(ordered$Start.Time, format = "%I:%M %p")
```

But after converting, an extra date string is adding to every rows

[image]

Please help me to remove the date string which has been added automatically to the time string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is a `POSIXct/POSIXlt` format, it would have the `Date` as well.  The prefix can be removed with `format`

```
ordered$Start.Time <- format(ordered$Start.Time, "%H:%M:%S")
```